# Unable to restart apache2 server on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install PHP and apache2 in my ubuntu 14.04. I installed PHP and apache2 through the following commands

```
  $sudo apt-get install php5-cli
  $sudo apt-get install apache2-bin
```

Now I just want to restart apache2 server on ubuntu system. But I am getting the "failed" error while restarting apache2. I mentioned the error below

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.
>
> Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

I need to restart my apache2 server on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the notice you are getting
Try

```
tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Or similar location on you system to check the Apache error log. This will clearly tell you where the error is. The most frequent one I get is that the log directory that I specified in the vhost configuration is missing

As of the notice, add

```
ServerName localhost
```

to your configuration and it will be gone.
In case your hostname is not localhost run

```
hostname
```

to learn what it is and then update ServerName directive with the proper value

On ubuntu the Apache conf file is in

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 2):

The following two lines in terminal worked for me.

```
1.echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf

2.sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/fqdn.conf
```

Hope this fixes your problem too.

Comment: Better yet just do a `sudo a2enconf fqdn.conf` and then a `sudo service apache reload`

Comment: I appreciate your comment but for me the above two lines worked fine and  sudo a2enconf fqdn.conf  gave me terminal message as :Conf fqdn already enabled . Hope that brings more light to this problem.

Comment: The reason you got the 'already enabled' message is that the `a2enconf` function does exactly what your second line does, just it's simpler to write/read (and you'd already done it your way). Either way, your method requires the third line, `service apache2 restart` to take full effect.

Comment: @WarrenSergent-spakatak.com-Thanks for sharing this info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a global Apache setting that stores `ServerName localhost` (assuming localhost is your hostname - if you are unsure, you can simply run `hostname` to see).

Whilst a lot of people will say to add this to the end of `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (depending on your version), this file will be overwritten if you update Apache at any point.

Apache allows you to have multiple configuration files enabled, and so I prefer to create a standalone file that stores this information, and to load it as well.

```
# Create a new config file, writing `ServerName localhost` to it
echo "ServerName localhost" | tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
# Enable the new config file
a2enconf servername
# restart the server
service apache2 restart
```

Note that you may need `sudo` for each of those commands if you are not using a `root` user.
This should work on Debian / Ubuntu and you'll notice the message has disappeared on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

add `ServerName 127.0.0.1` at end of file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` then restart apache, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add this following line in your apache2.conf file 
    ServerName localhost

Procedure: 
If you are using Ubuntu os then 
1.click alt+f2
2.type gedit
3.enter your password
4.open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
5.type ServerName localhost after ending of the file.
now go to terminal and restart the apache2 by typing 
sudo service apache2 restart
it's over