# PHP can not be run after intstalation but why?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

when restart apache on my linux terminal show the massage "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message" and phpmyadmin doesn't found on the local server. But why? I can not run php file after installing php.

Comment: Please see this for your first concern: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name. Can you elaborate on why you think php itself isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't able to restart apache2 sever on ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383534/cant-able-to-restart-apache2-sever-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

### 13.04 and older

This is just a friendly warning and not really a problem (as in that something does not work).

If you insert a

```
ServerName localhost
```

in either `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` in `/etc/apache2` and restart apache the notice will disappear.

If you have a name inside `/etc/hostname` you can also use that name instead of `localhost`.

And it uses `127.0.1.1` if it is inside your `/etc/hosts:`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myhostname
```

**Preferred method**

Troubleshooting Apache

If you get this error:

```
apache2: Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

then use a text editor such as `"sudo nano"` at the command line or `"gksudo gedit"` on the desktop to create a new file,

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn
```

or

```
gksu "gedit /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn"
```

then add

```
ServerName localhost
```

to the file and save. This can all be done in a single command with the following:

```
 echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn
But on Ubuntu 14.04:



echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
 sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

Don't forget the `".conf"` (without will not work).

### 13.10 or newer

As of Apache 2.4 - which is available by default as of 13.10 - you cannot use the method about adding a config file in the `conf.d` directory.

Apache no longer uses the `conf.d` directory. All the configuration files are stored inside `/etc/apache2/conf-available` directory and all the configuration files should now have a `.conf` extension.

In order to solve this message in Apache 2.4, we have to create a configuration file inside the `conf-available` directory. For example `servername.conf`.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
```

And inside this we just need to add one line

```
ServerName localhost
```

You can combine the previous two commands in one with:

```
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
```

If you want to use a domain name or any other name depending on the requirement its fine, just replace localhost with whatever you need. Next you have to enable this configuration. For this, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo a2enconf servername
```

`a2enconf` is a command to enable a configuration file in Apaches 2.4. Also note that servername on the above command is from the name of the configuration file `servername.conf`. If your configuration file was `ngenericserver.conf` then you would have to write `sudo a2enconf ngenericserver`.

After this reload the server and the above message will no longer bug you.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

or

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Now after this you will see that the message will not be shown again and the problem will be fixed.

Source: http://ngeneric.com/tutorials/linux/apache2/fix-could-not-reliably-determine-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-error

REFERENCE:https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name